How not to create python script after uv init command?
After using uv  init in a project directory, uv creates these files:
.git
README.md
pyproject.toml
hello.py
.python-version
.gitignore

I don't want it to generate hello.py. I want the others, but hello.py is unusable and i delete it every time i initialize a new environment.
I read uv help manual and searched but couldn't find my answer.
How can I prevent this command to generate hello.py?

You can't, not natively. There's an open issue requesting such an option, but it hasn't been addressed yet.
If you use Bash, you can add the following alias for convenience:
alias cleanuv="uv init && rm hello.py"

Then just use cleanuv instead of uv init whenever you want to start a new project.
